# Pass a lot of parameters to redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After the record is saved, I want to pass a lot of ids to the redirect link. I cannot pass it using the default cookie-based store because it exceeds the size limit. I just want to pass the information through the url. However I am getting the error `400 (Bad Request)` with the following.

```
redirect_to confirmation_my_records_path(invalid: ['case-1, 'case-2'] updated: ['case-3, 'case-4'] , saved: ['case-5, 'case-6'] )
```

which translates to:

> http://localhost:3000/my_records/confirmation?address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002013&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002015&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002016&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002017&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002018&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002019&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002020&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002021&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002022&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002024&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002027&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002028&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002032&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002033&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002034&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002035&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002037&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002038&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002041&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002042&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002043&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002046&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002047&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002048&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002050&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002051&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002052&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002053&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002056&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002058&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002060&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002061&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002062&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002064&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002066&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002067&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002073&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002084&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002088&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002090&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002100&address_blank%5B%5D=COCE-17-001962&address_blank%5B%5D=COCE-17-001965&address_blank%5B%5D=COCE-17-001972&address_blank%5B%5D=COCE-17-001973&address_blank%5B%5D=COCE-17-001984&address_blank%5B%5D=COCE-17-001985&address_blank%5B%5D=COCE-17-001986&address_blank%5B%5D=COCE-17-001988&address_blank%5B%5D=COCE-17-001990&address_blank%5B%5D=COCE-17-001992&address_blank%5B%5D=COCE-17-001994&address_blank%5B%5D=CONO-17-001197&address_blank%5B%5D=CONO-17-001198&address_blank%5B%5D=CONO-17-001203&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002349&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002359&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002378&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002379&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002380&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002381&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002384&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002387&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002113&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002116&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002122&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002132&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002197&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002198&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002203&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002205&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002226&address_blank%5B%5D=COCE-17-002032&address_blank%5B%5D=COCE-17-002040&address_blank%5B%5D=COCE-17-002050&address_blank%5B%5D=COCE-17-002058&address_blank%5B%5D=COCE-17-002063&address_blank%5B%5D=COCE-17-002064&address_blank%5B%5D=COCE-17-002073&address_blank%5B%5D=COCE-17-002079&address_blank%5B%5D=COCE-17-002082&address_blank%5B%5D=COCE-17-002085&address_blank%5B%5D=CONO-17-001219&address_blank%5B%5D=CONO-17-001243&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002447&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002456&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002464&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002471&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002477&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002478&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002481&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002489&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002497&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-001914&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-001925&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-001932&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-001937&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-001944&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-001952&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-001957&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-001959&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-001965&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-001966&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-001967&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-001971&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-001976&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-001983&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-001987&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-001999&address_blank%5B%5D=COCE-17-001888&address_blank%5B%5D=COCE-17-001892&address_blank%5B%5D=COCE-17-001925&address_blank%5B%5D=COCE-17-001928&address_blank%5B%5D=CONO-17-001160&address_blank%5B%5D=CONO-17-001161&address_blank%5B%5D=CONO-17-001162&address_blank%5B%5D=CONO-17-001165&address_blank%5B%5D=CONO-17-001172&address_blank%5B%5D=COSO-17-001687&address_blank%5B%5D=COSO-17-001710&address_blank%5B%5D=COSO-17-001731&address_blank%5B%5D=COSO-17-001734&address_blank%5B%5D=COSO-17-001735&address_blank%5B%5D=COSO-17-001774&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002231&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002256&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002257&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002279&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002304&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002306&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002308&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002314&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002316&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002319&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002326&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002332&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002238&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002251&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002253&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-002289&address_blank%5B%5D=COCE-17-002117&address_blank%5B%5D=COCE-17-002148&address_blank%5B%5D=COCE-17-002154&address_blank%5B%5D=COCE-17-002156&address_blank%5B%5D=COCE-17-002157&address_blank%5B%5D=COCE-17-002160&address_blank%5B%5D=COCE-17-002177&address_blank%5B%5D=CONO-17-001270&address_blank%5B%5D=CONO-17-001277&address_blank%5B%5D=CONO-17-001292&address_blank%5B%5D=CONO-17-001299&address_blank%5B%5D=CONO-17-001313&address_blank%5B%5D=CONO-17-001315&address_blank%5B%5D=CONO-17-001316&address_blank%5B%5D=COSO-17-001942&address_blank%5B%5D=COSO-17-001949&address_blank%5B%5D=COSO-17-002017&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002571&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002572&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002573&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002574&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002575&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002582&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002594&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002602&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002603&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002606&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002607&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002615&address_blank%5B%5D=COWE-17-002642&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-001801&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-001802&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-001803&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-001804&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-001805&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-001806&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-001807&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-001808&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-001809&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-001810&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-001811&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-001812&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-001813&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-001814&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-001815&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-001816&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-001817&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-001818&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-001819&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-001820&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-001823&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-001827&address_blank%5B%5D=CACE-17-001886&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002006&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002007&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002008&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002009&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002010&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002011&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002012&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002014&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002023&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002025&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002026&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002029&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002030&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002031&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002036&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002039&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002040&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002044&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002045&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002049&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002054&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002055&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002057&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002059&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002063&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002065&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002068&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002069&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002070&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002071&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002072&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002074&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002075&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002076&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002077&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002078&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002079&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002080&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002081&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002082&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002083&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002085&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002086&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002087&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002089&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002091&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002092&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002093&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002094&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002095&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002096&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002097&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002098&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002099&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002101&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002102&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002103&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002104&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002105&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002106&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002107&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002108&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002109&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002110&saved%5B%5D=CACE-17-002111&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001940&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001941&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001942&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001943&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001944&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001945&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001946&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001947&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001948&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001949&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001950&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001951&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001952&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001953&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001954&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001955&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001956&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001957&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001958&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001959&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001960&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001961&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001963&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001964&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001966&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001967&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001968&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001969&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001970&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001971&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001974&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001975&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001976&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001977&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001978&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001979&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001980&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001981&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001982&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001983&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001987&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001989&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001991&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001993&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001995&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001996&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001997&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001998&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-001999&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-002000&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-002001&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-002002&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-002003&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-002004&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-002005&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-002006&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-002007&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-002008&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-002009&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-002010&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-002011&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-002012&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-002013&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-002014&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-002015&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-002016&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-002017&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-002018&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-002019&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-002020&saved%5B%5D=COCE-17-002021&saved%5B%5D=CONO-17-001185&saved%5B%5D=CONO-17-001186&saved%5B%5D=CONO-17-001187&saved%5B%5D=CONO-17-001188&saved%5B%5D=CONO-17-001189&saved%5B%5D=CONO-17-001190&saved%5B%5D=CONO-17-001191&saved%5B%5D=CONO-17-001192&saved%5B%5D=CONO-17-001193&saved%5B%5D=CONO-17-001194&saved%5B%5D=CONO-17-001195&saved%5B%5D=CONO-17-001196&saved%5B%5D=CONO-17-001199&saved%5B%5D=CONO-17-001200&saved%5B%5D=CONO-17-001201&saved%5B%5D=CONO-17-001202&saved%5B%5D=CONO-17-001204&saved%5B%5D=CONO-17-001205&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001833&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001834&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001835&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001836&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001837&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001838&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001839&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001840&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001841&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001842&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001843&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001844&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001845&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001846&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001847&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001848&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001849&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001850&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001851&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001852&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001853&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001854&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001855&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001856&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001857&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001858&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001859&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001860&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001861&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001862&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001863&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001864&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001865&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001866&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001867&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001868&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001869&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001870&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001871&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001872&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001873&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001874&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001875&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001876&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001877&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001781&saved%5B%5D=COSO-17-001782&saved%5B%5D=COSO-1%E2%80%A6%E2%80%A6

What other options do I have to pass large amounts of data on redirect?

Comment: can i see an example of the url being formed by the function call above and the length that it is?

Comment: @MohammadAli I updated question with a snippet of what the link looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way I can see this being done is by the data up into multiple cookies, you could have every 100 or so lines placed into a cookie or have each parameter stored in a separate cookie so that you could fit into the 4 kilobyte maximum. The only alternative i see to this solution would be to show a form to the user on the redirect page, then using javascript to submit the form, you would have effectively submitted a form and created a post request without any interaction by the user.

Comment: Using the technique of breaking up the data into separate cookies worked, but why the 400 Bad Request? What was that error all about?

Comment: if the server finds that the size of the Cookie for that domain is too large or that some Cookie is corrupted, it will refuse to serve you the web page. it will show you 400 Bad Request, Request Header or Cookie Too Large error. This is typical for nginx servers. it could be a server security feature as your url is longer than the spec allows read more about that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers Please mark this answer as correct if it has helped you with your question

Comment: Something is still wrong. The data in one of the cookies is available after redirect. But the data in the other cookie is no longer available after the redirect.

Comment: the cookies need to be on the same domain as the page it is redirecting to. other than that i  have no idea why all of your cookies wouldent be showing,  if you open it up as a new question with a sample of your cookie setting code you can probably get more help, also feel free to upvote this answer if you like it to give me some points